# Django server stops during for loop

Tags: python, django, docx, doc

In my Django app I need to extract some data from files which could be around 500 in number and only of formats .doc and/or .docx. I've written the following

```
filenames=os.listdir(fpath)
for file1 in filenames:                      ## iterate each file in folder
    if file1.endswith('.doc'):               ## check if its .doc ?
        pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_MULTITHREADED)
        wordapp =win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application") 
        x = wordapp.Documents.Open(file1)
        my_list.append(x.Content.Text)
        wordapp.ActiveWindow.Close()
        wordapp.Quit() 
        ### Do some pattern matching on my_list for extraction of data and store it in DataBase

    elif file1.endswith('.docx'):
        file1=file1.encode('UTF8')
        file1=fpath+"\\"+file1
        document = opendocx(file1)
        body=getdocumenttext(document)
        # Do some pattern matching and store in DataBase
    else:
        print "File are not of required format"
```

Now my problem is that after first file in the folder has been processed the Django server hangs up. But if I run the same code as standalone python file then it works. Why is this happening and how to solve this issue ? Any help is appreciated in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: could you please post a minimum-example code that actually triggers the problem? also note your fist line as well as the `else` statement are wrongly indented

Comment: Noted and corrected! I'm using regular expression for extracting email-id,mobile number which works fine for .docx format (i.e. inside `elif`) but for .doc format (inside `if`) it just stops doing nothing.

Comment: There still seems to be an issue with indentation in the code above. Does the `for` loop actually have the same indentation as first line (`filenames=`). If not it will thrown an error; but if it is, see the [help on formatting code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). In any case, it seems you are only investigating so: in the `if` block, please add a print/logger calls in between lines or [enter `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and step through the lines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) and find your culprit. This should help you debug more easily

Comment: Sorry! this is my first time here and I'm tying to get used to it. I will try that.

Comment: @akki5256 - No problem, you are doing great for a first time! Looking again, you seem to be using COINIT_MULTITHREADED which I believe is intended to allow spawning threads by pythoncom library; you should be aware that you may encounter thread-safety issues when using django templates (and template tags) and orm calls. Hanging is a common symptom of running outside of the relevant thread.

Comment: This has probably nothing to do with the problem, but just a suggestion. Instead of doing `file1=fpath+"\\"+file1` it's always a good idea (e.g. portability reasons) to let python take care of the path separators using: `file1 = os.path.join(fpath, file1)`

Comment: @andzep : I agree. I shall use it in my code.Thanks!!

Comment: also if you're going to import `os.path`, you may use `if not os.path.exists(file1): continue` to [skip files that don't exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)

Comment: ... and one more thing to check. Is your server on production or dev? Are you getting any error messages (logs or emails) at all?  If you haven't configured your django app to log things, you definitely should. I'll write a small code-block in an answer with a basic configuration.

Answer (score 1):

To make debugging easy on django apps, you can setup a basic logging like this (if you haven't):

```
# settings.py
import logging

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(module)-20s %(funcName)-15s %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'log_file':{
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp.log'),
            'maxBytes': '16777216', # 16megabytes (to keep the file max. 16MB big)
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['log_file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'myapp': { # this will catch any log-calls inside your app 'myapp'
            'handlers': ['log_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

# somefile_to_debug.py

# ... use pformat to output rather complex data structures as pretty
#       strings (perfect for debugging)

from pprint import pformat
import logging

# Create an instance of a logger which will include the name of this module
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_function(bla, somedict):
    logger.debug(pformat({'bla': bla, 'somedict': somedict}))
```

Restart your app, and you can use tail to watch the output on your log-file on a terminal (sorry, don't know how to do this in windows, but in linux you'd do):

`tail -f myapp.log`